# One hydrogen atom universe. Is it possible to free the electron?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, thought-experiment

Let's assume a vast universe with only one hydrogen atom inside and some (unlimited amount of?) electromagnetic radiation to excite the atom.

Is it ever possible to free the electron according to the current physics? Why?

**Edit:**
I wonder if energy levels in an atom goes to infinity, and what we call *freeing an electron* -in our current universe- is just transferring the electron from one atom's very high energy level to the other's in an immeasurable /random way.

Comment: Yes, could you add why you think there would be a difficulty?

Comment: @JohnHunter I don't think there would be a difficulty in exciting the atom to higher levels (maybe there would). But what I am after is if the energy levels are infinitely many and what we call *ionization* is just due to the randomness (random fields etc) in our current universe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The [ionisation energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy) of hydrogen is about $13.6$ eV so if you add at least this much energy to the electron then you have freed it from the hydrogen atom. The ionisation energy is the analogue of escape velocity in planetary dynamics.

The free electron will still be attracted to the proton (because the photons that mediate the electromagnetic force have unlimited range) but it is no longer in a closed orbital.

Comment: Thank you. If there was a universe with only two celestial objects inside, wouldn't they start to orbit around each other no matter how far they are -provided that they have some velocity component perpendicular to the line connecting the two?

Comment: @Xfce4 No, if the relative speed of the two objects is high enough then a closed or bounded orbit will not be possible - the path of one object relative to the other can be  a parabola or a hyperbola.

Comment: This is what I mean. I think it cannot be a parabola, but an ellipse. Parabolas or hyperbolas should be approximations we use due to the randomness in our universe in which a celestial object might be captured by another one.

Comment: @Xfce4 You are incorrect. Parabolas and hyperbolas, like circles and ellipses, are conic sections and so are exact solutions to the two-body problem for an inverse square law such as Newtonian gravitation or classical electromagnetic attraction - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_problem for more details.

Comment: Wow, I suppose this the part Newtonian physics is incomplete :P Anyway, the mathematical explanation was cool, thanks for that. But does it sound possible to you that two celestial objects can get further and further from each other indefinitely? I don't tell this to insist on anything -just expressing my confusion- but, I really feel like the gravity will eventually stop the object and pull it back. In other words, I feel like the constant force of gravity will eventually decrease the finite amount of kinetic energy of the objects.

Comment: @Xfce4 Yes, in a two object universe it's entirely possible for the two objects to get further away from each other indefinitely. This is because the integral of the magnitude of the inverse square law attraction from an initial distance $r_0$ to infinity has a finite value, so the decrease in kinetic energy has an upper limit . See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential.

Comment: Ok. You say if the maximum work can be done by gravity is finite then it can be exceeded by higher amount of KE. Mathematically it makes sense, but imagining it does not :P Maybe this is a kind of Xenon paradox. Anyway. Thanks a lot for the information.